# Spring MVC RestController scope

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have the following `Spring` controller:

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        long val = counter.incrementAndGet();
        return String.valueOf(val);
    }
}
```

Each time I access the REST API, it returns an incremented value. 
I am just learning Java and I am wondering why it does not always return 1 as a new instance of `AtomicLong` must have been created each time the request comes.

Comment: Why do you think that it's creating a new instance?

Comment: @chrylis: I am originally from .net background and just had a comparison with it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, the `TestController` bean is actually a singleton. [`@RestController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) annotation declares a Spring [`@Component`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html) whose scope is by default [`SINGLETON`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableBeanFactory.html#SCOPE_SINGLETON). This is documented in the [`@Scope`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html#scopeName--) annotation:

> Defaults to an empty string ("") which implies SCOPE_SINGLETON.

This means that it will be the same instance of `TestController` that will handle every requests. Since `counter` is an instance variable, it will be same for every request.

Comment: Is it a good practice to keep it singleton or set the scope to so-called `prototype`?

Comment: @BabuJames For a `Controller`, I would say it is better to keep it a singleton. `Controller`s are not typically stateful so it makes sense to make them singleton.

Answer (score 4):

A `@RestController` is not created for each request, it remains the same for every request. So your `counter` keeps its value and is incremented each time.